# How to distribute lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

Let's say I have two lists like below:

```
list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = ['a[3]','a[2]','a[1]','a[0]','b[3]','b[2]','b[1]','b[0]','c[3]','c[2]','c[1]','c[0]']
```

And there's input text like below ('random_text' is content that is not related to the data):

```
random_text

put A_upper_case_here    
random_text    
put a[3]_lower_case_here    
random_text
put a[2]_lower_case_here    
random_text
put a[1]_lower_case_here    
random_text
put a[0]_lower_case_here    
random_text
put B_upper_case_here    
random_text    
put b[3]_lower_case_here    
random_text
:
put c[0]_lower_case_here    
random_text
```

What I want is to put each data of the list into the input text like below and extract it to output:

```
random_text

put A_upper_case_here 
A
random_text    
put a[3]_lower_case_here    
a[3]
random_text
put a[2]_lower_case_here
a[2]    
random_text
put a[1]_lower_case_here
a[1]    
random_text
put a[0]_lower_case_here
a[0]   
random_text
put B_upper_case_here
B    
random_text    
put b[3]_lower_case_here
b[3]    
random_text
:
put c[0]_lower_case_here
c[0]    
random_text
```

Above is a simple case, So, I've tried a `for` loop in case of large amount and
divided the case into 'upper_case' and 'lower_case' like below:

```
list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = ['a[3]','a[2]','a[1]','a[0]','b[3]','b[2]','b[1]','b[0]','c[3]','c[2]','c[1]','c[0]']

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fnw:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if "upper_case" in line:
            f.write("\n {0}" .format(list1))

        elif "lower_case" in line:
            f.write("\n {0}" .format(list2))

        else: 
            f.write(line)
     fnw.write(f)
     fnw.close()
```

However, Since Now I might be a beginner to a python, It didn't work at all.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: This really looks like an `xy problem`.  What are you really trying to accomplish?  What is the text input you'd like (whether stored in file or lists), and what is the desired output?

Comment: it's hard to tell what is literal and what is a placeholder value in your example

Comment: There's input text on the first draft. list is nothing to do with input. I am trying to put the data of list into the input by using python, and then make it into output. I am assuming I already have the above two lists. and using that lists with python code, I need to make output.

Comment: Are inputs like `A_lower_case_here` or `b[1]_upper_case_here` accepted? What outputs do you expect for them? What if `list1` and `list2` had different values? What about inputs that are in the same form but not in the list like `z[4000]_lower_case_here`?

Comment: that input is just text. not a form of *.py . And I already assumed that two lists have different values. if the data is like z[4000]_lower_case, then that's not gonna be my consideration.

Comment: So just echo back the same value so long as it is in `list1` for `upper_case_here`, or `list2` for `lower_case_here` ?

Comment: Yes, That's right

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this code does what you want:

```py
import re

list1 = ['A','B','C']
list2 = ['a[3]','a[2]','a[1]','a[0]','b[3]','b[2]','b[1]','b[0]','c[3]','c[2]','c[1]','c[0]']

upper_set = set(list1)
lower_set = set(list2)

pattern = re.compile('^put (.*)_(lower|upper)_case_here\s*$')

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.txt', 'w') as fnw:
    for line in f.readlines():
        fnw.write(line) # This copies all input to the output, remove this line if you don't want that
        match = pattern.search(line)
        print(line, match)
        if match:
            content = match.group(1)
            case = match.group(2)

            case_set = upper_set if case == 'upper' else lower_set

            if content in case_set:
                fnw.write(content)
                fnw.write('\n')
```

It uses regular expressions to check if a line is in the correct format and to extract the relevant parts. Regular expressions take a while to learn, but I'll explain what each part of the one used here (`^put (.*)_(lower|upper)_case_here\s*$`) does:

- `^` means that nothing can come before the `'put'`. Without this, lines like `'random_text...put A_upper_case_here'` would be accepted
- `put`  matches text `'put '`
- `(.*)` match any text at all and capture it in group `1`
- `_` matches text `'_'`
- `(lower|upper)` matches either `lower` or `upper` and captures it in capture group `2`
- `_case_here` matches text
- `\s*` matches any whitespace in any amount. The `*` means it allows any amount of it. It includes the new line at the end of every line and also the extra spaces at the end of lines in your sample input text.
- `$` this marks the end of the input. If this were not here, lines like `'put a[0]_lower_case_hereafter'` would be accepted.

The `upper_set = set(list1)` and `lower_set = set(list2)` lines convert your lists to sets. A set is like a list but has no ordering and it is much faster to check if something is inside a set than if it is in a list. Since we are doing a lot of these checks, sets are the right data structure to use here.

The other changes:

- `f` is opened in read-only mode and refers to the input file, so it should not be written to - only `fnw` is written to.
- `fnw.close()` is not needed because the `with` statement does that for you already.